# GEM Promega 2 not producing sounds

Tags: digital-piano

My son is practising piano on a GEM Promega 2 digital piano. Before we went on vacation I completely turned it off. When he wanted to play again today the piano does not produce any sound via the attached (working) speakers, the MIDI signal however is sent out.

Usually the GEM also took a few minutes to load the internal sounds into memory this step nows seems to happen in just a few seconds.

Is there any key combination to run some internal tests or any other thing we can try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit terse, but I found reset & diagnostics info on [Sweetwater](https://www.sweetwater.com/sweetcare/articles/reset-diagnostics/)

> Hard reset: Hold Performance Edit while powering up
>
> Diagnostics: Hold down Sounds button while powering up. Use Sounds button to step thru tests.

Comment: I am not sure if the article refers to the actual Promega 2 however it is running again. Keeping certain buttons pressed when powering up seems to be the right way.